# Can I assign a Dictionary as an attribute of another class instance?

Tags: java, object, dictionary

I have a class called Node. For an instance of Node, I would like to assign a dictionary as an attribute to keep track of the Node object's neighbors and the weight of the path connecting the Node to each of its neighbors.

Example:

1->2---7 (Node 1 connects to node 2 with a weight of 7)

1->3---5 (Node 1 connects to node 3 with a weight of 5)

...

I want to create a Node object "1", which has a Dictionary attribute with (key, value) to equal (neighbor, weight).

In this case 1's dictionary should be [2:7, 3:5].

```
import java.util.Dictionary;

public class Node{

    public int i;
    public Dictionary neighbors = new Dictionary();
    public int w;

    public Node(int i, int j, int weight){
        this.i = i;
        this.neighbors = neighbors.put(j, weight);

    }   
}
```

Current Error: ./Node.java:6: error: Dictionary is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Is this possible? And if so, how would it look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html):

> The `Dictionary` class is the abstract parent of any class, such as `Hashtable`, which maps keys to values.
>
> NOTE: This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the `Map` interface, rather than extending this class.

Use a `Map`.

```
Map<Node, Integer> neighbors = new HashMap<>();

// ...

neighbors.put(j, weight);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not instantiate an abstract class. This doesn't mean you can't have it to be the type for an instance variable.

But, you will need to implement a subclass of Dictionary, not Dictionary itself.

```
public Dictionary neighbors = new Dictionary();
```

should be

```
public Dictionary neighbors = new DictionarySubClass();
```

Also: it's good practice to keep your instance variables private, and to use mutators (getters and setters) to manipulate them.

Comment: There's no such `class` as `DictionarySubClass`. But a quick look the [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) suggests two things. 1) The only implementation of `Dictionary` is `Hashtable` and 2) `Dictionary` is deprecated.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: it was merely an example of how to deal with an abstract class, which is what he is having trouble with. For all I know, Josh created a DictionarySubClass, so I can't state there isn't one.
This was not meant as a "copy and it'll work" solution, rather an "here is the idea how to ..."

Comment: Granted that could all be true, but I would postulate that someone who doesn't know what an `abstract class` is most likely wouldn't have implemented a `Dictionary` themselves. You have answered the XY problem here and ignored the underlying problem. It helps, when answering questions from beginners, to try and work out _intent_.